# How to get Percentage from the summation of the total hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently, I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t."Resource" AS "Email",
                t."project id" AS "project_id",
                sum(t."Hours Logged") AS "total hours"
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT "Resource",
                   "Hours Logged",
                   "proposals"."Clickup Id" AS "project id"
   FROM "daily hours",
        proposals AS "proposals"
   WHERE "When Logged" >= (CURRENT_DATE - 7)
     AND ("Space Id" = "proposals"."Clickup Id"
          OR "Folder Id" = "proposals"."Clickup Id"
          OR "List Id" = "proposals"."Clickup Id")) AS t
GROUP BY (t."project id",
          t."Resource")
```

The output of this query is this:

```
| Email          | project_id     | total hours |
| ---------------| -------------- | ------------|
| mail@mail.com  | 1              | 6           |
| mail2@mail.com | 2              | 5           |
| mail3@mail.com | 1              | 7           |
| mail4@mail.com | 2              | 3           |
| mail@mail.com  | 3              | 4           |
```

So now I want to write a query that sums the `total hours` which gives an `overall total hours` and group by `project_id` then find the percentage using this formula  `"total hours" / "overall total hours" * 100`

So the output will be thus

```
| Email          | project_id     | total hours | overall total hours | percentage |
| ---------------| -------------- | ------------| --------------------| -----------|
| mail@mail.com  | 1              | 6           | 13                  | 46.15
| mail2@mail.com | 2              | 5           | 8                   | 62.5
| mail3@mail.com | 1              | 7           | 13                  | 53.84
| mail4@mail.com | 2              | 3           | 8                   | 37.5
| mail@mail.com  | 3              | 4           | 4                   | 100
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can apply  a window function to an aggregate `sum(sum(t."Hours Logged")) over(..)`

Comment: @Serg please an example will be nice. Tried the above and i was getting an error

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a window function to an aggregate, demo:

```
with t(Resource,project_id,hours) as (
 -- emulates result of the subquery
 select 'mail@mail.com ', 1,  6 union all
 select 'mail2@mail.com', 2,  5 union all
 select 'mail3@mail.com', 1,  7 union all
 select 'mail4@mail.com', 2,  3 union all
 select 'mail@mail.com ', 1,  6 union all
 select 'mail2@mail.com', 2,  5 union all
 select 'mail3@mail.com', 1,  7 union all
 select 'mail4@mail.com', 2,  3 union all
 select 'mail@mail.com ', 3,  4          
)
select t.Resource AS "Email",
       t.project_id ,
       sum(t.hours) AS "total hours",
       sum(sum(t.hours)) over (partition by t.project_id) "overall total hours",
       sum(t.hours) / sum(sum(t.hours)) over (partition by t.project_id) "percentage"
from t
GROUP BY t.project_id, t.Resource
order by t.Resource,t.project_id
```